# How do I get Regex to only allow positive/negative digits and decimals

Tags: regex, intellij-idea

I am looking for a regex expression that allows positive numbers (eg. 1), negative numbers (eg. -1), positive decimal numbers (0.5) and negative decimal numbers (-0.5).

I am currently using the regex     ^-?[0-9?.]*$ .

This regex works however it does not limit the input to just one minus symbol or decimal. Instead the user can type in thing like --------------0.....5...--- .

I need a regex which only allows one of each symbol and in the appropriate places.

I have tried the regex's below but none of them work - ie. that none of them allow the input of a [-] or [.] at all.

```
^-?[0-9](\.\d+)?$
^-?(?!.*-.*-.*)(?!.*\..*\..*)\d+(?:\.\d+)?$
/^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/
-[0-9]*\.[0-9]+
^-?[0-9](\.\d+)?$
/^-?\d*\.?\d+$/
/^-?\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

It seems that the only way my codebase/ui will allow such symbols is using the regex i have at the minute. Is there any slight modification i could make to it that will limit the -'s and .'s?

Thanks so much

eg.     ^-?[0-9?.]*$ allows input -12-12-24---333....5555

Comment: What, exactly, is the expected result? Should `-12-12-24---333....5555` match and return `-12`, `-12`, `-24`, `-333`, `5555` or should it fail since it is not a number as a whole?

Answer (score 2):

`-?` (`?` is a quantifier meaning one or zero occurrences)

If the number is decimal, `(\.\d+)?` will ensure that a number must come after the `.`

```
^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$
```

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/ZMdiN2/1)